# product of digits as a single-digit number

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy

I am trying to compute the product of non-zero digits,
until the result is a single-digit number. For example, the number 512983 is 2, because 5×1×2×9×8×3 = 2160 and 2×1×6 = 12 (note the omission of the zero digit) and 1 × 2 = 2. But every time I run this I only get 0

```
    def prod_digits(n):
        a = 1
        for each in str(n):
            a = a * int(each)
        return a

    prod_digits(123)
```

Comment: What happens if you `print a` and `print each` inside the loop?

Comment: I want it return the answer not print it

Comment: Yes.  Printing it will help you debug.

Comment: the mistake is you are setting `a = 0`, so anything multiplied with 0 is 0. So set a as 1

Comment: Like @Stack said.  Debugging (by checking the values) would've likely shown you this ;-)

Comment: def prod_digits(n):
    a = 1
    for each in str(n):
        a = a * int(each)
        print a 
        print each 
        
    return a
prod_digits(123)       this returns: 1
1
2
2
6
3
6

Comment: This problem gives different results depending on the order of calculation! Try with `12011210345003`

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
def prod_digits(n):
    a = 1
    for each in str(n):
        if each is not '0':
            a = a * int(each)
    return a

a = 123
while (a > 10):
    a = prod_digits(a)

print a
```

Comment: This is broken for `a = 12011210345003`, it returns `4` i/o `2`

Comment: @ReblochonMasque: But...it is 4? 1x2x1x1x2x1x3x4x5x3 = 720, 7x2 = 14, 1x4 = 4.

Comment: `2 x 2 = 4 * 3 = 12 = 2  * 4 = 8 * 5 = 40 = 4 * 3 = 12 = 2`  HAHAHAHA... the result varies depending on the order of operations! :D :D

Comment: @ReblochonMasque I understood his question to be, work through all the digits, get a result, then work through all the digits again, etc.  Not continuously reduce > 10 results to single digits.

Comment: Nice. This is actually faster than my recursive function with `reduce`.

Comment: Yeah, I'm thinking there might be some uncertainty in how the question was posed. New poster, so we may never know :/

Comment: `a *= int(each) if each is not '0'  else 1` would be cleaner and a bit better.

Comment: Good point.  The OP doesn't seem as comfortable with Python though, so the above code was meant to be easily readable/understood at the expense of conciseness.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple issues with your code

1. Since initial value of `a` is 0, any subsequent multiplications will give 0. Change it to 1.
2. Your function needs to be called recursively until the argument to function is a single digit.
3. You need to ignore 0 while multiplying digits.

Comment: how do I do the second part? @kaustubh

Comment: @kerj74 - In case this is your first introduction to recursion, I would suggest looking for some basic problems on recursion, like factorial, fibonacci sequence etc. However, If you are more comfortable with iteration, it can be done that way too. Use nested loops and in outer loop, keep checking the length of intermediate string/array

Answer (score 0):

Or you can use the reduce function from `functools`:

```
from functools import reduce

def compute_nz_product(n):
    digits = [int(c) for c in str(n) if c is not '0']
    result = reduce(lambda x, y: x*y, digits)
    if result < 10:
        return result
    else:
        return compute_nz_product(result)

print(compute_nz_product(512983))
```

Output:

```
2
```

Comment: Used `if result < 10` as suggested by others.